# sed -f with gnu parallel

Tags: bash, sed, gnu-parallel

What is the correct way to parallelize

`sed -i -f patterns files*`

with GNU `parallel`?

I have pattern files with hundreds of patterns and I need to process >1GB files.

Comment: Could you be clearer about the approximate numbers please? You could parallelise across the patterns or across the files or some other way. How many patterns files? How many lines each? How many files to search in?

Comment: Typically the pattern file has ±400 patterns and `files*` consist of >1000 files with various size 10kB - 1GB

Comment: If the pattern file allows, it might be best to split each input file into smaller parts, process using parallel and sed and then recombine. This perhaps will allow parallel to process larger files quicker.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
parallel sed -i -f patterns {} ::: files*
```

---

If you have too many files that your shell cannot handle the volume, you can send the filenames on `stdin` with null-termination as follows:

```
find . -name "files*" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | parallel -0 sed -i -f patterns {}
```

Comment: Yes this is the obvious solution. I was just trying if @ole-tange doesn't have some super-performant ace up in his gnu `parallel` sleeve :).